# Cannot copy object constructed from default-constructed array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, stdarray

After 1 or 2 hours spent to isolate a compilation error surrounded by a metaprogramming mess generating awfull compilation messages, here is a minimal and simple example that illustrates my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <class Crtp, class... Types>
struct Base
{
    Base(const Types&... rhs) : 
        data(std::forward_as_tuple(rhs...)) {;}
    std::tuple<Types...> data;
};

struct Derived 
: public Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3>>
{
    template <class... Args> 
    Derived(Args&&... args) :
        Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Derived a(std::array<double, 3>({{1, 2, 3}})); 
    Derived b(a);
    Derived c(std::array<double, 3>()); 
    Derived d(c); // Not working : why ?
    return 0;
}
```

This is compiled with g++ 4.8.1 and I do not understand exactly why the compiler complain when I try to copy `c` in `d` and not `a` in `b`.

Here is the error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Derived::Derived(Args&& ...) [with Args = {Derived (&)(std::array<double, 3ul> (*)())}]’:
main.cpp:28:16:   required from here
main.cpp:20:73: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3ul> >::Base(Derived (&)(std::array<double, 3ul> (*)()))’
         Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {;}
                                                                         ^
main.cpp:20:73: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:10:5: note: Base<Crtp, Types>::Base(const Types& ...) [with Crtp = Derived; Types = {std::array<double, 3ul>}]
     Base(const Types&... rhs) : 
     ^
main.cpp:10:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Derived(std::array<double, 3ul> (*)())’ to ‘const std::array<double, 3ul>&’
main.cpp:8:8: note: constexpr Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3ul> >::Base(const Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3ul> >&)
 struct Base
        ^
main.cpp:8:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Derived(std::array<double, 3ul> (*)())’ to ‘const Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3ul> >&’
main.cpp:8:8: note: constexpr Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3ul> >::Base(Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3ul> >&&)
main.cpp:8:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Derived(std::array<double, 3ul> (*)())’ to ‘Base<Derived, std::array<double, 3ul> >&&’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
Derived c(std::array<double, 3>());
```

is a declaration of a function `c` which returns a `Derived` and takes one unnamed argument of type *pointer to function that takes no argument and returns `std::array<double, 3>`*.
Therefore `Derived d(c)` tries to call `Derived` constructor from the function `c`. This is what GCC is saying here:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Derived::Derived(Args&& ...) [with Args = {Derived (&)(std::array<double, 3ul> (*)())}]’:
```

Try this:

```
Derived c{std::array<double, 3>{}};
```

Comment: Is it a bug in GCC or is it normal ?

Comment: @Vincent: This is normal (and famously known as [*The most vexing parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)) according to the C++ standard.

Answer (score 3):

Works with:

```
Derived c(std::array<double, 3> {});
```

The compiler considers the parameter in

```
Derived c(std::array<double, 3>());
```

to be a function.

clang gives a warning for this:
`!!warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declarator.`

Comment: Deserves Emphasis: use the C++11-style initializer => saves much trouble, including the trodden caveat of declaring a function where you mean to construct an object.

Answer (score 0):

First make your Derived constructor explicit.
If that does not help add copy constructor, but I do not think that would be required